# Eclipse RCP toolbar separators dont show up

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm having a problem with the main toolbar in my Eclipse RCP application. The added separators in my plugin.xml never show up. Their visibility are all set to **true**

Is this a known bug? Because programatically added separators in some views contributions show up just fine.

See attached pic:

[image]

Here is the plugin.xml part:

```
<menuContribution
        locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
     <toolbar
           id="hu.clickandlike.wfbpmn.application.toolbar1">
        <command
              commandId="hu.clickandlike.wfbpmn.application.menu.command.new"
              icon="icons/1390594879_document-new.png"
              label="New"
              style="push">
           <visibleWhen
                 checkEnabled="false">
              <with
                    variable="hu.clickandlike.wfbpmn.application.menu.command.new.state">
                 <equals
                       value="true">
                 </equals>
              </with>
           </visibleWhen>
        </command>
        <command
              commandId="hu.clickandlike.wfbpmn.application.menu.command.open"
              icon="icons/1390594932_document-open.png"
              label="Open"
              style="push">
           <visibleWhen
                 checkEnabled="false">
              <with
                    variable="hu.clickandlike.wfbpmn.application.menu.command.open.state">
                 <equals
                       value="true">
                 </equals>
              </with>
           </visibleWhen>
        </command>
        <separator
              name="Separator 1"
              visible="true">
        </separator>
        ...
```

Comment: I think separators are not shown if they are at the beginning or end of a bar or menu.

Comment: That makes sense. But I also have a separator after my first two icons (after the command.open command) and it isnt visible either.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse 4.3? https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=413213

Comment: THank you Calon, it seems this is my problem. :( Probably I can update the visibility later via code.

Comment: I'd recommend you to register for the bug. The more people watch it, the faster it is solved ;).
Edit: well, mostly :P